# How to get the checked objects in django view with ajax?

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I am very new to ajax. Here I have a django form and inside the form there is a form group of checkbox.
What I want here  is, from the checkbox if the user check some user object I want to get it in the django view immediately before the form submit. And if the the user uncheck this It should be removed from  django view also. How can I do this ?

After form submit it works fine but I want to get the checked user before the form submits.So I think in this case ajax will be required. But I am very beginner in ajax so I got stuck here.

template

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input class="checkbox1" name="users" type="checkbox" value="{{user.pk}}"
                       id="user{{user.pk}}"/>
                <label for="user{{user.pk}}"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

jquery

```
 <script>
   $(function(){
    var checked_lists = [];
    $(".checkbox1:checked").each(function() {
        checked_list.push(this.value);
    });
     $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'my_url' %}",
         data:{
        checked_Lists: checked_list,
    }
        }
      });
   });
</script>
```

views

```
 print(self.request.POST.getlist('checked_lists'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In you case you need to pass **`checked_list[]` javascript list** to view so need ajax
for that

- and handle **ajax request** base on **`checkbox change`** event

```
<script>
   $('.checkbox1').change(function(){ // checkbox1 change event 
    var checked_lists = [];
    $(".checkbox1:checked").each(function() {
        checked_list.push(this.value);
    });
    var formdata = new FormData();
    $.ajax({
            formdata.append('checked_list',checked_list)
            formdata.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken',$('input[type=hidden]').val());
            $.ajax({
                url:"/profile_upload", //replace with you url 
                method:'POST',
                data:formdata,
                enctype: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                processData:false,
                contentType:false,
                success:function(data){

                   alert("Display return data"+data)
                },
                error:function(error){
                    alert(error.error)
                }
            });
    });
   });
</script>
```

## views.py :You define view base on your logic

```
def <view-name>(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
       user_list = request.getlist('checked_list')
       return JsonResponse(status=200,data={'data':'success'})
   else:
       return JsonResponse(status=203,data={'error':'unauthorize request.!!'})
```

If you use post request to define `csrf_token` so pass them if your script
code in single page `formdata.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken',{% csrf_token %});`through those link and do

[Ajax Request For Sumbit Data](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

if you get error on it, let me know

Comment: i update my answer see you need to handle request on change of checkbox read about csrf token for post request if you use get not use csrf so read if any issue let me know

Comment: how can i get the checked users in django view ?

Comment: I update my answer you check and also read link a give how to handle ajax request base on the form **POST** method